# why is urllib2 taking a long time to read?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm writing a simple program to compare HTML pages but my current bottleneck is reading the HTML files.  Specifically the code:

```
    htmldata1 = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
    htmldata2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2).read()
```

The url's are from IMDB.  I don't know why it takes so long (average ~9 seconds).  It may be downloading the images when I just want the html text to search with regular expressions.  I have never used urllib2 so any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

An example url I use is

"http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast"

Comment: It would be nice if you could give an actual url, so that others can give it a try and see if they experience the same behavior.

Comment: Tried using `urllib`, not `urllib2`?

Comment: @Eduardo just gave an example url.  My bad.  Abien, the issue persisted with both urllib and urllib2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is just super-slow to load (on the server's end). This is on gigabit fiber:

```
In [4]: url1 = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast"

In [5]: %time result = urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()
CPU times: user 56.3 ms, sys: 21.6 ms, total: 77.9 ms
Wall time: 2.16 s

In [7]: %time result2 = requests.get(url1)
CPU times: user 29.5 ms, sys: 6.35 ms, total: 35.9 ms
Wall time: 2.18 s
```

And outside of python entirely:

```
$ time curl -o/dev/null "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2173k    0 2173k    0     0   537k      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--  540k
curl -o/dev/null   0.01s user 0.03s system 0% cpu 4.074 total
```